# How do i elegantly reference return values in multiple-return-value-functions in Lua?

Tags: lua

say i have a function:

```
function func()
    return 1, 2, 3
end
```

Is there a way to elegantly reference individual return values? such as

```
if func() == 1 then
  print("stuff")
end
```

but instead reference the second or third returned value?

i realize you can do this

```
if ({func()})[2] == 2 then ...
```

but it just looks awful, and might as well just

```
_,v = func()
if v == 2 then ...
```

i'd like to do something like this

```
if func() == _,2 then ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be `select`:

```
if select(2, func()) == 2 then ... end

print(select(1, func()) -- prints 1 2 3
print(select(2, func()) -- prints 2 3
print(select(3, func()) -- prints 3
print(select('#', func()) -- prints 3, the total number of arguments received
```